# Setting JQueryMobile Popup's data-position using JavaScript

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, popup

`$('#popupDiv').popup("open");`

This programmatically opens a JQueryMobile pop up, but I want to know if it is possible to change or set my popup's settings, such as `data-position` and `data-transition` along with my code above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the [jQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html):

> Positioning options By default, popups open centered vertically and
>   horizontally over the thing you clicked (the origin) which is good for
>   popups used as tooltips or menus. The framework also applies some
>   basic collision detection rules to ensure that the popup will appear
>   on-screen so the ultimate position may not always be centered over the
>   origin.
>
> For situations like a dialog or lightbox where the popup should appear
>   centered within the window instead of over the origin, add the
>   data-position-to attribute to the link and specify a value of window.
>
> It's also possible to specify any valid selector as the value of
>   position-to in addition to origin and window. For example, if you add
>   data-position-to="#myElement" the popup will be positioned over the
>   element with the id myElement.

```
<a href="#positionWindow" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="slideup">

    <div data-role="popup" id="positionWindow">
        <p>I am positioned to the window.</p>
    </div>
```

You can add `data-transition="slideup"` (or the transition of your choice) to the link, as well as other positioning options outlined in the docs link at the top of my answer.

Answer (score 19):

You can do:

```
$('#popupDiv').popup("open", {positionTo: '#mydiv'});
```

'origin' is not working for me in version 1.2 though.

see: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/methods.html

Comment: This is still working in jQuery Mobile 1.4.5! Saved my day, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

yeah the right way to do this is use event.target like this

```
$('#popup').off('taphold').on('taphold', function (e) {
     $('#popupDiv').popup("open", e.target);
});
```

incidentally, this code then places a popup if you tap hold the button and a click event is like this would mean a normal click still works

```
 $('#popup').on('tap', function (){
     var url = $(this).attr('url');
     window.open( url, '_parent');              
 });
```

nb: I added "`url='google.com'`" to the markup and made `href='#'`